# spring integration time out clients

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, tcp, spring-integration

My scenario with spring integration is:

1. tens producer that send the data using a custom protocol(size and content)
2. I have to decode this custom protocol and then handler the result.

So I tried lots configuration, the best for this moment is the follow:

```
<bean id="serializer" class="com.MySerializerDeserializer" />
<task:executor id="myTaskExecutor" pool-size="5-300" queue-capacity="500000"/>
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverTcpConFact"
    type="server"
    port="5566"
    using-nio="true"
    single-use="false"
    so-timeout="5000"
    task-executor="myTaskExecutor"
    deserializer="serializer" 
    serializer="serializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="tcpInboundAdapter"
    channel="tcpInbound"
    connection-factory="serverTcpConFact" />

<int:channel id="tcpInbound" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="tcpInbound"
    ref="importService"
    method="handler" />

<bean id="importService" class="com.MyImportService" />
```

The serialization class is:

```
public class MySerializerDeserializer implements Serializer< MyMessage >, Deserializer< MyMessage > {

    @Override
    public MyMessage deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
        int size = dis.readInt();
        byte[] b = new byte[size];
        dis.read(b);
        MyMessage s = new MyMessage ();
        String value = new String(b);
        s.setTest(value);
        return s;
```

I use this code to thest the server:

```
class SimpleThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            String id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            try (Socket echoSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5566)) {
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
                for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                    String s = id + " " + i;
               dos.writeInt(s.length());
                    dos.write(s.getBytes());
                    dos.flush();
                    System.out.println(id + " - " + i + " - " + s.length());
                }
            }
```

When I execute this with a single thread works fine when I try to execute more than one threads Like:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 new SimpleThread().start();
 }
```

The spring integration server gets stuck and I have the follow WARN:

```
WARN _[m [THREAD ID=myTaskExecutor-1] 2014-06-25 12:42:18 WARN  org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory:566 - Timing out TcpNioConnection 127.0.0.1:56273:5566:4e3caf61-1101-4881-a1cf-1c31610b33f3
```

And it doesn’t work, The server can't recive the messages.

With this error:
[image]

Where am I wrong? 
Thank you.

EDIT

I modified the thread poll in this way:

```
<bean id="myTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.integration.util.CompositeExecutor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
            <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="io-" />
            <property name="corePoolSize" value="4" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="8" />
            <property name="queueCapacity" value="50000" />
            <property name="rejectedExecutionHandler">
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.util.CallerBlocksPolicy">
                    <constructor-arg value="10000" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
            <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="assembler-" />
            <property name="corePoolSize" value="4" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
            <property name="queueCapacity" value="50000" />
            <property name="rejectedExecutionHandler">
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.util.CallerBlocksPolicy">
                    <constructor-arg value="10000" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And the server is more responvive, but the I still have the problem

**EDIT*****

The import service is:

```
public class ImportService {

    public void handler(MyMessage inp) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "******" + inp.getTest());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your test exactly as described (copied your code) and all worked as expected. 500 messages delivered to the other side.

I suggest you turn on TRACE level logging, and maybe add some debug logging to your deserializer.

Comment: Thank you @Gary, The problem is when I execute more threads.
In this case I should revice 500 * 5 messages.
With single thread works fine.
I'd like to know if this is the best way for this situtazion.

Comment: I just ran it with 5 client threads and your task executor and all ran fine; received 2500 messages. Is your `MyImportService` thread-safe?

Comment: Thank you @Gary, I edited the question with my `MyImportService`
The class just print the the test property `test`
I follow the example on github:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/tcp-client-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/tcpclientserver/EchoService.java

Comment: I don't know what to say; I took your code and added it to the sample (https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/SO140625) and it all works fine for me. Here's the commit with the changes (https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/2865f1c1214acffac4fe3353ad10c833dd1bfd97). Can you be more specific than "does not work" ?

Comment: really thank you for your help. I edited the question with the error message. The problem is that the clients disconnect the connection and the server is blocked for a few seconds, and print the warn: Timing out `TcpNioConnection 127.0.0.1` and the error: `Failed to write to pipe
Timed out waiting for buffer space at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection$ChannelInputStream.write(TcpNioConnection.java:662)`

Answer (score 0):

@JR You may want to take a look at this example which is similar to yours.

```
https://github.com/rajeshgheware/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/spring-integration-samples-tcp-concurrent-server
```

I tested this piece of code  for 3900 concurrent clients successfully.