# Spring integration send ack using gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a producers( write in CPP) that send to “spring-integration server” the binary-data.
And it works correctly as :
[spring integration time out clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406645/spring-integration-time-out-clients)

Now I have to send a reply (like an ACK) to the producer.

I have read about the gateway, but actually I’m confused.
My configuration is:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverTcpConFact"
    type="server"
    port="5566"
    using-nio="true"
    single-use="false"

    task-executor="myTaskExecutor"
    deserializer="serializer" 
    serializer="serializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="tcpInboundAdapter"
    channel="tcpInbound"
    connection-factory="serverTcpConFact" />

<int:channel id="tcpInbound" />


<int:service-activator 
    output-channel="tcpOutbound" 
    input-channel="tcpInbound"
    ref="importService"
    method="handler" />

<bean id="importService" class="my.ImportService" />

<int:channel id="tcpOutbound" />

<int:gateway id="mygateway"
    service-interface="my.IpMyGatway"
    default-request-channel="tcpInbound"
    default-reply-channel="tcpOutbound"
    default-reply-timeout="6000"/>
```

I also have an custom serializator, the problem is that the my spring integration server doesn’t send the reply.

I need that the reply executes:

```
@Override
    public void serialize(MyMessage arg0, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         logger.info("serialize messages");
// here I have to write my ACK ! ( .. or not?)
    }
```

And then sends the message to the producer for each message.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why [`<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-gateways) isn't enough for you...

There is just enough to generate a reply message from `service` and gateway will send it ot the client as response.

The simple sample:

```
<ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewaySerializedNio"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        request-channel="serviceChannel" />

<channel id="serviceChannel" />

<service-activator input-channel="serviceChannel"
        ref="service" method="process"/>

<beans:bean id="service" class="com.my.proj.MyService" />
```

The return value from `MyService#process` method will be serialized to the TCP socket.

Comment: Thank you @Artem Bilan, but I don't understand what do you mean for  `reply message`. Could you exaplin better please?

Comment: Added sample to the answer